# ASP.NET related error

Tags: asp.net

If you could help me with my problem, I'd really appreciate it. I'm unable to open my website in another computer, The following error occurs:

```
 Server Error in '/WebSite2' Application.

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\evisen\Desktop\Amy the  conqueror\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\evisen\Desktop\Amy the conqueror\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

 Source Error: 

 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

I hope I've been as specific as I can be. Thank you!

Comment: this is my connection string 

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="C:\Users\evisen\Desktop\Amy the conqueror\WebSite2\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Answer (score 1):

This error generally comes when there is some problem in your connection string. Try to check your connection string.

Also check this related [forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1830924.aspx). Hope that helps!